# How much does the .NET Framework rely on the Windows API?

Tags: .net, windows, unmanaged, native

I know some of the .NET Framework library (FCL) wraps Windows API calls, but I don't know how much. All of it? Most of it? Only a little bit?

Let's say I write a typical winforms business application in C# using only managed code. How much of my "managed" application is really "unmanaged" under the covers?

Comment: None of it.  It's executing via the framework, which is running it natively because you installed the native binary for the framework.

Comment: @Charles - It is all converted into the same CRL so I don't understand the reason behind this question.  Besides you can look at most of the source to the .NET Framework if you wanted.  I would say many of the windows and dialogs classes are simply wrappers to Win32 API at least for the Win32 forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let's say I write a typical winforms business application in C# using only managed code. How much of my "managed" application is really "unmanaged" under the covers?

In Windows Forms, nearly everything is a thin wrapper over a managed Windows API.  Windows Forms Controls even expose their native control handle via the [Handle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx).

That being said, if you use WPF, for example, much more of the underlying logic was written in managed code.  At some level, of course, things always shell out to the operating system - but much of the framework (WPF, WCF, etc) is higher level abstractions written in managed code, built on top of the lower level wrappers around the native API.

That being said, the level of managed code vs. native core varies greatly, depending on the type in question.  The beauty of this, though, is that, with .NET, you really don't have to care about whether the underlying implementation is native or managed, only whether it's a resource which requires cleanup via `IDisposable` or similar.

Comment: Reed, can you please explain this "At some level, of course, things always shell out to the operating system"? What does that really mean? Is "the operating system" the Win32 API, or is Win32 just one of many APIs on top of the OS? Or is "the operating system" a lower level for which all APIs are an abstraction?

Comment: @Charles: Everything's eventually getting pushed down to some level where it's being converted into instructions that will be executed by the hardware - so it's just many levels of abstraction.  Where do you want to stop peeling back the onion?

Comment: Reed, I do understand that everything eventually gets down to the hardware. But you specifically mentioned the OS. I'm just not clear on how many layers there are and which might be bypassed. For instance, does it go `.Net FCL` -> `[optional?] Win32` -> `OS` -> `Hardware`. (Hardware meaning everything from assembly down to CPU instructions).

Comment: @Charles: Depends on what portion of "FCL" you're talking about - certain parts layer on top of Windows API, certain portions don't...

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by putting "optional" at the Win32 layer. So is my layering right? You know, maybe I should just make this a separate question. :)

Comment: @Reed: Can you give some examples of parts of FCL that do not go through Win32 API?

Comment: @Arun: Some things have been re-implemented in managed code that used to use the Win32 API.  However, WPF uses Direct3D to render, for example, instead of calling Win32 API drawing calls.

Answer (score 1):

> How much of my "managed" application is really "unmanaged" under the covers?

100% of it. Managed is just lives on top of an unmanaged OS, which of course lives on unmanaged hardware.

> All of it? Most of it? Only a little bit?

I mean, I have no idea how you want to quantify it. Public surface methods? Lines of code? Total number of method invocations over all the C# code in the world? Who cares really, though? Most of the UI Windows-y code in .NET (WinForms, WPF) is going go through the Win API at some point. So is a lot of other code such as code that interacts with the file system, WCF, ADO.NET, etc.

What engineering problem is this going to help you solve?

Comment: It won't help me solve a specific engineering problem, which admittedly means it falls outside the guidelines for SO questions. However it will improve my foundation knowledge as a .NET programmer and I thought it was something other people might wonder about too.

Comment: @Charles: I have to admit, I have never even considered this question before, and I can't see how it will make me a better programmer. I write for to solve problems for my clients. I don't see how knowing how much of the code is unmanaged or relies on Win API makes me solve their problems more better.

Comment: Okay Jason. I don't really understand why you're telling me this. Is this your way of saying my question is pointless, stupid, or just somehow annoys you? Because it feels like thinly-veiled criticism, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Charles: Huh, no. I was genuinely curious why you were curious about this. The point of my statements was to give you an angle to elaborate on why you were curious about this, from the perspective of general understanding, or how it might help you help your clients. Absolutely no criticism was intended at all. I'm not going to waste my time typing answers or comments to questions I find annoying or stupid. I'm engaging you and your question because I'm curious what would make someone interested in it.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I just like to know as much as I can about what's happening under the hood, even if I don't see a specific present need for the knowledge. I think the more understanding I have about the hidden aspects of a complex system, the better positioned I am to comprehend whatever technical questions may confront me about that system in the future - even if the connection between the esoteric knowledge and the specific question is never obvious to me. I know that's vague but it's the best I can offer.

Comment: As for this question, the reason it occurred to me is that I noticed a lot of "managed to native transition" lines in the call stack while debugging, and it got me wondering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a purely technical answer, the entire applicatin, at some lower point, is unmanaged. But, since you are asking from a .NET perspective ...

It really depends what the application does. As you are using winforms, the application will use more than some other types (drawing libraries, for example). Add on some Internet capabilities, sockets, etc. and the amount of reliance goes up.

The more custom code you have, not using .NET libraries, the higher percentage is managed by the CLR. the same is true with many of the more "helper" functions in .NET. Any communication code will get down to unmanaged code, in the framework. The same is true for graphics libraries. If I think a bit longer, I can also touch some others.

My guess for a Windows Forms application. Some to most of the code is unmanaged as you crawl the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There have been various releases of source code to the .NET runtime and class libraries over the years.  Not every release and not all of the code, but good chunks of it.  So you could start with that and assess the relationship between managed and unmanaged yourself.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx

I recall looking at the "reference source" for version 1.0 when that was released and was pleasantly surprised about how much of the class libraries (like the string class, regex class, XML classes, etc...) were written in managed C# code.  And the lowest layer of classes that make use of OS services (like threads, mutexes, file i/o) were P'Invoking into Win32.  But that was a long time ago.